# @IBOutlet vars in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, var

I am trying to make a todo app in swift from this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEYHd91YzNI) when I get to around the 5 minute mark, I run the app and get:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key notesTestView.'

I have seen some other users getting this but no fix has become apparent. I have been searching for around three days now trying to figure this out.

It has something to do with the titleTextField and notesTextView variables. Whenever I use a '!' while declaring them, Xcode gives me this error when I click on the '+' in the app. If I don't use the '!', Xcode doesn't let me compile. If I don't use either '?' or '!', Xcode doesn't let me compile. Any thoughts?

I am trying to declare the variables as follows (Xcode default):

```
@IBOutlet var titleTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var notesTextView: UITextView!
```

And Access them like this:

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    var dataSet:NSMutableDictionary  = NSMutableDictionary()
    dataSet.setObject(titleTextField.text, forKey: "itemTitle")
    dataSet.setObject(notesTextView.text, forKey: "itemNote")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what the problem is: you are trying to use Key-Value Coding to set the value of a key named "khvj" on an object that does not have a key named "khvj".

So the problem is not where you are looking.

Look for a call to `setValue(value:forKey:)` somewhere where you are passing "khvj" as the key parameter. Then check if the object you are calling that method on has a property named "khvj".

If you yourself are not calling `setValue(value:forKey:)`, then it could be that it is being automatically called as part of the process of an object being loaded from a xib or storyboard file. Check to make sure that in your xib or storyboard files you are not trying to wire any outlets to a property "khvj" that does not in fact exist any more.

Comment: I see what you mean and I did get rid of some junk outlets that I had, but now it is saying: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key notesTestView.'" again

Comment: "notesTestView" != "notesTextView". That is your problem.

Comment: basically, whenever the runtime complains that something is not KVC compliant for a given key, then either you or the xib-deserialization mechanism are looking for a key that does not exist on that object. It's either an obsolete outlet hanging around in IB, or it's a misspelling on your part probably.

Comment: That was it. I feel really silly :/ Thank you so much.

Comment: np. When trekking through a new forest, it's always hard to know which tree matters!

Answer (score 0):

"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key khvj"

This usually comes from a referencing error.  If for example you accidentally have two IBOutlets from one label or other UI object, this confuses the compiler and you get the error.  Go into the utilities panel and clicl on the Connections inspector after selecting an object in the storyboard.  It will show you the outlets.  See if you have two different outlets for one label for example.

Comment: I just checked and they are all in order :/ Any other thoughts?

Comment: This can also happen if you have the wrong class named fir a storyboard view.  maybe a class name is MyClass, but in the utilities inspector you have it listed as ViewController.  But this is a referencing error of some type.  Alternatively check that you do not have a missing reference.

Comment: If you post to github I can take a look and pinpoint it for you.

Comment: give me a few minutes

Comment: That would be awesome if you could take a look!

Comment: you didn't post the full project, just some of the files

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to GitHub, is it better now? I think I added the Xcode project file

Comment: Okay, I was able to deal with it.  You have a large number of referencing outlets you can see in the Connections Inspector that are not used in the program or are duplicates with odd names like "notesTestView" .  I highly recommend selecting every label, button, textView and textField and deleting every referencing outlet, then reconnect them all.  But only one to the needed IBOutlet or IBAction.  When I fixed one, I would get another and another.  So I deleted all, reconnected and life was good.

Answer (score 0):

That error typically means that there's a problem with the IBOulet, or IBAction hooked up to them - often either a missing connection, or a typo in the name. It's an error with some property or method called "khvj" - wherever that might be in the project...

The tutorial also uses custom subclasses for the UITableViewController & other ViewController - you need to ensure that you've set the custom classes properly in the storyboard, or else the viewcontrollers won't know that they're supposed to contain the custom methods & outlets you've added.

Finally, following that same tutorial at ~5:00, you need to initialize the UITextFields or else they don't exist when you try to get the text from them. Using the explicit `!` says "this is definitely a non-nil UITextField," but then if it's actually nil, that's a problem.

```
@IBOutlet var titleTextField: UITextField = UITextField()
@IBOutlet var notesTextView: UITextView  = UITextField()
```